# Request advice on inplementation Modbus-RTU in Tokyo

Tags: modbus, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I would like to implement a FREE Modbus-RTU master or slave in my Delphi 10.2 Tokyo development environment application. I searched the Internet but only found old or paid versions. Who can help me out?

Thanks,

Henk.

Comment: This website do not allow asking for library or component set. You could ask such question there: https://en.delphipraxis.net/forum/3-delphi-questions-and-answers/

Comment: Okay,

Thanks, I will do that.

Henk